# Der Tag wird gedacht or Dem Tag wird gedacht?

Tags: dative

Which sentence is correct and why?

> Der Totale Verteidigung Tag wird hier jedes Jahr gedacht.
>
> Dem Totale Verteidigung Tag wird hier jedes Jahr gedacht.

I initially wrote "Der Tag... wird gedacht", but was told that I should use "Dem Tag ...".

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a reason why you think one of those sentences is correct?

Comment: What is the sentence supposed to mean? Is the verb *denken* or *gedenken*?

Comment: In English, the verb is "commemorate". I am not sure which verb should be used in German.

Comment: Is this about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_defence#Total_Defence_Day ? Then if I understand correctly, on the Total Defence Day, the surrender of the British to the Japanese is commemorated (and not the Total Defence Day itself), and the German sentence would have to be entirely different.

Comment: As a German my first association with "Totale(r) ...." is the "Totaler Krieg" proclaimed in Nazi Deutschland. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totaler_Krieg.I would avoid using a phrase with "Totale(r) ..." in German, because for me it always caries a negative feeling.

Comment: Yes, as in the English Wikipedia article. How would I phrase that correctly in German? Thanks.

Comment: @Mosg The German expression for the same concept is 'Gesamtverteidigung' and a per se more or less correct translation would be 'Tag der Gesasmtverteidigung'. You can't however expect a German reader to understand what is ment with that expression. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesamtverteidigung

Answer (score 4):

Es wird gedacht *des Tages*. The verb "gedenken" is used with Genitiv.

PS. Whatever "der totale Verteidigung Tag" should mean, this is not a correct German.

Comment: How about "Tag der totalen verteidigung" ?

Answer (score 2):

Following your comment, it should be

> Am »Tag der totalen Verteidigung« [or »Tag der Gesamtverteidigung«] wird der Kapitulation der Briten gegenüber den Japanern gedacht.

(Other German native speakers please advise on the preposition that needs to follow Kapitulation ...)

Comment: I'd suggest *vor* as preposition, since it's *vor jemandem/etwas kapitulieren.* See also the 3rd entry in the paragraph *Charakteristische Wortkombinationen* [at Wiktionary](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kapitulation)